# ComboBox shows empty list

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to use different objects at JavaFX and stacked on combobox. It shows list without elements.

```
public class Controller extends Application {

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public Label label1 = new Label();
public CheckBox cbox1 = new CheckBox();
public ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
         "Option 1",
                "Option 2",
                "Option 3"
        );

public ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
......
<ComboBox id="comboBox" fx:id="comboBox" prefWidth="150.0" 
GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
......
```

Comment: <ComboBox id="comboBox" fx:id="comboBox" prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />

Comment: Pls add sample.fxml. I guess comboBox is not a part of your scene. @FXML public ComboBox comboBox;

Comment: Please note: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]."

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the `ComboBox` from your `FXML` into your `Controller`. Instead, you are creating a brand new `ComboBox` (which is not being displayed in your scene).

You should remove this line:

```
public ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);
```

And replace it with this:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox comboBox;
```

Then it's just a matter of setting the items for the combobox:

```
comboBox.setItems(options);
```

---

**Why?** The `@FXML` annotation tells JavaFX that the `ComboBox` you refer to on the following line has been defined in your `FXML` file. This allows JavaFX to "inject" that object into your controller.

> **Side Note:** It is generally not a good idea to use your main class as your controller class (I recommend creating a separate controller class for your FXML). Your controller class should also include a `private void initialize()` method (annotated with `@FXML`). This is where you can setup the parameters for your scene's controls. Most introductory JavaFX tutorials will walk you through that process.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use setItems as comboBox have no methods. I have added a bunch of imports  and also InteliJ Idea do not purposes to add one as it does usually. What can be wrong?

Comment: If your `comboBox` has *"no methods"*, then you've done something horribly wrong.

Comment: @OleksandrZnachkov did you import `javafx.scene.control.ComboBox` ?